# Down voted question has a lot of comments saying the question is unclear, no comments however describe how

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I asked this question today: [What is a good approach to get equivelent base color of another base color with opacity](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/113007/what-is-a-good-approach-to-get-equivelent-base-color-of-another-base-color-with?noredirect=1#comment167538_113007)

However the question seems to appear unclear to the viewers.

What I dont get is:

1. Noone is asking any questions to the question which might make the question more understandable
2. Everyone seems to be agreeing that the question is very unclear, however some of the same people have posted good responses (IMO) afterwards (No editing has happened meanwhile)
3. I am asking for a tool / software which could benefit this issue, yet some people think I might be looking for an JavaScript answer and saying photoshop would be perfect for this - Without even saying how.
4. I am not a common user on this stackexchange but I am a frequent user of others. When I comment an answer is not what I am looking for, it seems that is bad/rude or something and now it seems like I am getting "personally attacked" for having done this. (quotation marks, because I don't know a good english translation for what I am trying to say. Personally attacked is an absolute overstatement).

I don't understand why the question in itself is bad (hence the downvotes) I haven't received a 'closed for unclear tag' which I think would be appropriate if that was the issue. I am definitely confused with the approach of this stack exchange, as it seems to differ a lot from my other experiences on other stack exchanges.

How can I make this question better? because I still believe it to be a good question and related to graphic design

Comment: re: "_I haven't received a 'closed for unclear tag'_" I know you can't see the current vote tallies at your rep level, but just so you are aware there are currently 4 "unclear" close votes. GD.SE is a small site with not a lot of active close voters, so 4 votes within 3 hours is significant.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. I just don't necessary think downvotes is always right on unclear questions but should be used for bad questions. I know the 2 ovarlaps and is hard to define.

Comment: The question is not bad. You have had several comments about clarifying the terminology of how it has been formulated and those comments are precisely to help you find a clear answer. Maybe the down votes are not for the question itself but for not having a slightly more open attitude.

Comment: I just received this perfect answer: **@JonasPraem harmfully the case is closed. But try formula Y=255 - P*(255-X) where X is a RGB number, P=opacity (0...1), Y=new RGB number which should give the same appearance with 100% opacity as X gives with 100p% opacity against white background. Note: the white background should be a white object, not the artboard white. White background object is color managed.** This answers my problem exactly even though I didn't know what I was looking for. For me this is why you keep a question open for atleast 12 hours, before closing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I will try to answer this question, as I was not involved in the closing of the question, nor in the (chat) discussion regarding the question, so hopefully no one will see me as biased.*

<sub>* Note: I am not a mod, so I cannot see deleted comments.</sub>

---

First I want to say: if users are saying that a question is unclear, they are *not* doing so to annoy you or discourage you, they are saying so because they think the question is unclear. In my many years on this stack I have seen **none** of the users involved do anything that wasn't for the betterment of the stack.

Second I want to say: a question being put On Hold is not a punishment. It is only a way to tell users and passers-by that the question as it stands needs improvement, and until then it is best to leave it alone. A lot of questions (maybe a mod can give you a percentage) do get reopened later and receive very good answers and leave the asker very happy.

Third, we are a small and active community, so votes, answers and other activities are usually done much faster here than on bigger stacks (such as Stack Overflow). The fact that a (bad) question stays open longer on SO does not mean users are more lenient there, it just means it takes them longer to vote because there is a higher question-to-active user ratio.

---

How do you expect people to help you find what you are looking for if you yourself are unclear what you were looking for? (quote: "this is exactly was I was looking for, without knowing what I was looking for")

We are not mind readers, nor can we read between non-existent lines. If you require a specific answer to a specific problem, you need to ask a specific question.

---

Now I will try to answer your different points.

> 1. No one is asking any questions to the question which might make the question more understandable.

You also never gave them a chance to do so. You immediately went into full assault mode and started accusing people that they weren't helping, and attacking them as if they purposely tried to undermine you and you question.

And they did ask. "Did you read this?", "What colour mode are you using?", "Did you try screenshots?", "How do you want to implement the solution?", "Why is colour picker not a viable option?" are ***all*** questions about the question.

> 2. Everyone seems to be agreeing that the question is very unclear, however some of the same people have posted good responses (IMO) afterwards (No editing has happened meanwhile)

Yes, and as you pointed out yourself, those answers varied *wildly*. That is because the question is unclear as to what you actually want, but people are still attempting to help you anyway (in spite of you being aggressive and having a general bad attitude).

So they start giving answers to the question they *think* you are asking. And one happened to be spot on. Most were not (as you were eager to point out).

> 3. I am asking for a tool / software which could benefit this issue, yet some people think I might be looking for an JavaScript answer and saying Photoshop would be perfect for this - Without even saying how.

Well, a tool / software is about as concrete as a philosophical argument, there are about a million colour tools out there. Photoshop is a tool, so that answer is technically correct.

What you want is a ***methodology***, as is also evident in the fact that the answer you declared to be finally correct is a... **formula** and not a **tool/software**.

> 4. I am not a common user on this stackexchange but I am a frequent user of others. When I comment an answer is not what I am looking for, it seems that is bad/rude or something and now it seems like I am getting "personally attacked" for having done this. (quotation marks, because I don't know a good english translation for what I am trying to say. Personally attacked is an absolute overstatement).

To be clear, you did not "comment an answer is not what I am looking for", you literally wrote "that source doesn't even closely answer the question", which is *not* the same in *any* way. It is rude and unnecessarily antagonising.

English is not the first language of many users on this stack. Of all the users you interacted with, only one is a native speaker that I know of. Yet they all seem to be able to be polite and constructive.

> How can I make this question better? Because I still believe it to be a good question and related to graphic design.

Well, the person who guessed what you were asking correctly, has now done the work for you. I suggest you study the edit closely. You will notice the question is now "How do I calculate" which is infinitely more specific than "any good tools?".

Some specific pointers (which are also stated in [help](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)):

1. Ask one specific question. (Your original post had five questions)
2. Explain how you encountered the problem, and what you tried unsuccessfully. (You explained how you encountered the problem, kind of, but not how you tried to solve it)
3. Make sure the answer can be specific. (You asked about any tool, of which there are millions)

   4. If you are struggling to ask your question, mention it. We will gladly assist in getting a concept to words, but only if you are willing to be helped.

Also, *no one* has said it is a bad question, nor that it is not related to Graphic Design. Only that it was unclear *to them*, and it might help to specify some concepts.

---

## Conclusion (I do really hope you read the whole thing)

You say you do not understand the 'accusations about your attitude' while you have been unnecessarily antagonistic and uncooperative.

You say your question *is* good and on topic, while no one denied it was. They just asked for clarification to be better able to *help you*.

You say you question *is* specific, while it clearly is not. The answer you eventually said was correct answered none of the five original questions in your post.

You say no one helped you make the question better, but attack everyone who even tries to give you a hint or guide you, and insist on seeing every comment as an attack on you or your post.

You ask for leniency as English is not your first language, which is fair, yet you do not grant other users that same leniency.

You say it is off-topic to speak about your character. Yet users were commenting on your behaviour, not your character.

You say our community is different to other stacks, maybe we are. We have an unusually high answer percentage, a small but active core of users, a high vote and answer speed, and a clear idea of what is on topic and what is a decent question. Maybe other stacks are more lenient, slower and less clear. We are not other stacks. You are welcome to join our stack, and even question our approach, if you can be a polite and constructive community member.

Comment: 1/5 I really wan't to add to this. While my question did not look for a specific answer, it was still a specific problem - Unclear or not. I am not trying to argue that my question was clear enough, but I did get a couple of very useful responses. The problem to me is that the comment section turned into a witch-hunt after I had answered 1 or 2 responses. It might have seemed rude - idk, but from there the post was never about the question anymore - only MY attitude and behaviour. While you might think this has nothing to do with my character, I think this is really untrue.

Comment: 2/5 They were assuming I had bad intentions in my comments. Honestly if a person asks a Javascript question on SO, they will not accept answers to a 10 line blog post about C# - which I think was the case of the FIRST responses I got. It might have seemed rude, but the person hadn't read the question at all. - it is about opacity levels in colors. The focus was towards my attitude the whole time - even in this post, where I can't seem to place where I have seemed rude. Then I really think it is an attack on my character when the output of peoples comments are biased towards my username.

Comment: 3/5 My attitude might have been rude, but I had to argue 1 against 4 all the time as a newcomer to the site. I don't think that is necessary and I still think I am met with a very hostile environment here. Keep to the case/question and avoid commenting on how I am as a person. This is the professional me - I keep my stones unturned & I am very direct (seems rude at times, but never the intention). I don’t think it is fair to neglect the question because of judgement towards my attitude. I think we should keep this out of the stack.

Comment: 4/5 If my comments have been rude, they should be deleted and that should be it, the validity of the question shouldn’t be affected by my ‘character’ / attitude / approach - call it what you will. I think this answer is really good and to the point, but I disagree with the clearness of my question. One person did manage to find a perfect solution even though that was a formular, and not a software. This is even better than a software because the user understood my problem, hence he understood my intentions.

Comment: 5/5 The question was edited to a more clear question. But of course the question is more clear when you know the answer. I didn’t, people didn’t - one user did. Which is exactly the point of the site is it not?

Comment: I did also receive a downvote on a old question of mine (over 1 year old) YESTERDAY. I think this confirms the witch hunt agenda which happened

Comment: This is one of the best meta responses I've seen on SE. Good job, PieBie

Comment: Thank you Zach, that means a lot.

Comment: @ZachSaucier Seconded. This is exactly why I keep on bugging PieBie to become a mod one day.

Answer (score 6):

Moderators have discussed it and this is what we've found:

Zach could've set a better tone initially had he not said, "you could easily look this up yourself" before providing you with a link. That said, he did believe the link would help.

You in turn could've said, "thanks Zach but that's not what I'm looking for. I need X, Y, Z. Perhaps that wasn't clear in my question."

And then this entire discussion could've been avoided.