# 2019 Moderator Election Q&A - Questionnaire

Tags: discussion, election

In connection with the moderator elections, we are holding a Q&A thread for the candidates. Questions collected [from an earlier thread](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3621/2019-moderator-election-qa-question-collection) have been compiled into this one, which shall now serve as the space for the candidates to provide their answers.

Due to the submission count, we have selected all provided questions as well as one of our back up questions for a total of 10 questions.

As a candidate, your job is simple - post an answer to this question, citing each of the questions and then post your answer to each question given in that same answer. For your convenience, I will include all of the questions in quote format with a break in between each, suitable for you to insert your answers. Just [copy the whole thing after the first set of three dashes](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/dec46b41-ef93-4e6b-8adc-6047d4c2982e/view-source).Please consider putting your name at the top of your post so that readers will know who you are before they finish reading everything you have written, and also including a link to your answer on your nomination post.

Once all the answers have been compiled, this will serve as a transcript for voters to view the thoughts of their candidates, and will be appropriately linked in the Election page.

Good luck to all of the candidates!

**Oh, and when you've completed your answer, please provide a link to it after this blurb here, before that set of three dashes. Please leave the list of links in the order of submission.**

To save scrolling here are links to the submissions from each candidate (in order of submission):

- [Mr. Online](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3637/41100)
- [PieBie](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3639/41100)

---

> 1. What is your relationship, interest and experience in the field of Graphic Design?
> 2. Beyond merely having additional privileges and access on the site, why would you want to be a moderator?
> 3. What is your view on the interaction between our stack and other stacks? Do you think cooperation is necessary, or even viable? How would you approach members of those communities into our community? Would you encourage our members to become active in those communities also?
> 4. A moderator role that is unusually relevant in this community (as opposed to others) is taking “political” initiative, i.e., steering the community by means of meta posts and similar. What are your ambitions in this respect? Are there any pressing issues you would like to address and how do you plan to do so?
> 5. Name an individual action that showcases your suitability as a moderator, for example an individual meta post, review action, or comment (please provide a link to it). Why do you think that this a good example?
> 6. [Recently](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3598/welcome-to-the-new-graphic-design-stack-exchange), there have been tentative ideas to be more open to Critique questions than we have been in the past. What is your stance on this and the way it is being decided? Were/are there things you would do differently? How would you contribute to this process and discussion?
> 7. How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?
> 8. How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc a question that you feel shouldn't have been?
> 9. A diamond will be attached to everything you say and have said in the past, including questions, answers and comments. Everything you will do will be seen under a different light. How do you feel about that?
> 10. How many graphic designers does it take to change a lightbulb?

Answer (score 16):

You wanted answers? You got 'em! Prepare for a wall of the stream-of-consciousness ramblings of a madman! I take full responsibility, including typo's, stupid jokes and unfinished sente

If you want more info on anything, you'll probably find me in chat.

---

> What is your relationship, interest and experience in the field of Graphic Design?

I took some introductory courses in college. I think I'm an OK designer, though I lack a lot of experience to be called a professional. My day job is front-end developer, so I convert designs to code and work with assets delivered by clients. *I have seen things you people wouldn't believe, thousands of unnamed layers, embedded documents within embedded documents, raster images saved as vector files. All those, horrors, will remain in my nightmares, forever.*  Joking aside, I'm handling design related things almost every day of my life, and I dabble in design in my free time.

---

> Beyond merely having additional privileges and access on the site, why would you want to be a moderator?

[I want the power!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-dJolYw8tnk)

Apart from that, I have a lot of experience with online platforms, and being a moderator (or some such role) on a lot of them. I know a good moderator can make a big difference in user experience and perception of a community.

What I'm hoping to bring to the table in this mod team is exactly what I've been doing before: being active in chat, being active on Meta, helping users both new and old use and understand the Stack. Might has well have the ♦ to go with it.

What I won't be bringing to the table is: loads of time, nightly chat sessions, rudeness, politics, bigotry, a demigorgon or power plays.

---

> What is your view on the interaction between our stack and other stacks? Do you think cooperation is necessary, or even viable? How would you approach members of those communities into our community? Would you encourage our members to become active in those communities also?

I knew this would bite me in the rear end :D

I do think there is a pretty large crossover between some stacks and us, most notably UX. I think it would be interesting to reach out to their regular users (i.e. their chat room). Maybe share our bountied questions in their chat and vice versa. Reboot the monthly design challenge and advertise it in their chatroom also. Just a few ideas.

---

> A moderator role that is unusually relevant in this community (as opposed to others) is taking “political” initiative, i.e., steering the community by means of meta posts and similar. What are your ambitions in this respect? Are there any pressing issues you would like to address and how do you plan to do so?

To answer the last first: no, I don't think there are any pressing issues at the moment. Picking up the Critique discussion where we [left it off](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3598/welcome-to-the-new-graphic-design-stack-exchange)  might be interesting.

I think I have already been contributing to these discussions, and I don't plan on stopping. Frankly, I don't think making me a mod is going to have a huge impact on my contributions in this regard.

---

> Name an individual action that showcases your suitability as a moderator, for example an individual meta post, review action, or comment (please provide a link to it). Why do you think that this a good example?

I think most of my Meta contributions qualify, but I'm still proud of [this answer](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3508/down-voted-question-has-a-lot-of-comments-saying-the-question-is-unclear-no-com/3510#3510). I think it strikes the right balance between being *strict* without being *belligerent*. Although I am not sure the same answer from someone in the mod team would've been accepted so readily by the asker.

I also still stand by [this answer](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3382/41100).

---

> Recently, there have been tentative ideas to be more open to Critique questions than we have been in the past. What is your stance on this and the way it is being decided? Were/are there things you would do differently? How would you contribute to this process and discussion?

As I said, picking up this discussion would be interesting.

Although the Meta Q&A format has its limitations (eg for extended discussions), it does force one into shaping their thoughts before posting. So I think it's a good process to have.

All in all, how this site works should be decided by its users: the community. Ironically, the only answers to the mentioned post have been given by mods. But to be honest, I don't see this as a problem: the discussion is open to the community members, whether they choose to participate is up to them.

---

> How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?

Talk it over with the mod team to see if they noticed something similar or I'm just seeing ghosts. If I'm not alone, talk to the user to see what they think might be the issue, and if they're willing to change their behaviour/tone of voice. If they persist, issue a warning. And if really necessary a suspension after ample warnings.

---

> How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc a question that you feel shouldn't have been?

Mods are volunteers and people. I might take it up in (mod) chat with them, especially if I notice this more than once. If there really is an obvious dispute between multiple mods, I think it needs to be taken to the community. If it's nothing too big or if it's just me, I'll probably [Let it go](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/FbbpXLUP_qY/maxresdefault.jpg).

---

> A diamond will be attached to everything you say and have said in the past, including questions, answers and comments. Everything you will do will be seen under a different light. How do you feel about that?

I stand by everything I said and did in the past, so I do not mind it getting the *mod stamp*.

Bu I'm very weary of always wearing the mod hat, because it means I will no longer be 'neutral', a role I have taken up quite a bit in the past. A user who had a bad experience with one mod will be weary of all mods, because they've been talking 'behind the screens'. It's good to have a few non-mod regulars who can then step in to 'negotiate'. By nominating myself, I'm hoping another regular will step up to take this role.

---

> How many graphic designers does it take to change a lightbulb?

One to design what the new iLightbulb™ will look like.

Additionally:

- one Art Director to 'streamline' the designs of iLightbulb™,
- one Project Manager to map out the iLightbulb™ project in Kanban views and Gantt charts,
- one Scrum Master to keep an overview of the iLightbulb™ project scope and align interests,
- a crew of engineers to design the machine that will produce the new iLightbulb™ in China,
- a Safety Advisor to make sure everyone follows protocol,
- several lawyers to consider the legal implications of the information gathering capacities of iLightbulb™,
- no one to write documentation for the iLightbulb™ project,
- several Marketeers to push ads onto social media telling people interested in shoes that this is the new iLightbulb™ to have because it connects to your smartwatch,
- a Programmer to write an API for iLightbulb™ so it can integrate with your CRM,
- several middle Managers telling everyone to copy the competition's uLightbulb™,
- and finally one CEO to take none of the responsibility if it all goes South.

Comment: You have free time? *eyebrow*

Comment: Ultimately, all time is free :D

Comment: Time itself is merely a construct.

Comment: @Scott is free itself merely a construct too?

Comment: Is this the real life?

Answer (score 1):

To save scrolling [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/election) are links to the submissions from each candidate (in order of submission):

## Hello from Mr.Online (not a website)!

---

> 1. What is your relationship, interest and experience in the field of Graphic Design?

Graphic Design is **my mother** and I'm **a baby** in her womb if you ask me about the relationship! So, I'm a lover of graphics rather than interested boy and when it comes to  experience then I would say one thing: ***"Games was my Passion back then but now it's my Profession!"*** so as you've read, I'm professionally UI (User Interface) and UX (User Experience) designer who does some weird and cool graphical things all the time! Around 2 years passed since I'm doing this professionally but started contributing and using GDSE to achieve the next stage!

> 2. Beyond merely having additional privileges and access on the site, why would you want to be a moderator?

To reputed @Scott and all of the others. I'll say: ***"As we believes that GOD is everywhere yet we still goes to holy places"*** same goes for me, I'm not even sure that I'll use *all additional privileges and access* because I'm not experienced to such tasks. Still there is one thing I can assure and that is: ***"I'll try my best to make this site better in every possible way that I can, So that more and more graphic lovers can get used to it"***

> 3. What is your view on the interaction between our stack and other stacks? Do you think cooperation is necessary, or even viable? How would you approach members of those communities into our community? Would you encourage our members to become active in those communities also?

Nice question from @PieBie. As I follow in my work and life: ***"cooperation is not just necessary but completely viable if you're opting to provide something that is good or even better"***! So, interaction comes very handy when you want to learn/help in other stacks. In my case, joining the stack overflow became a very plus to sharpen my code related stuff which later greatly helped me in automation of my design progress. Once you're trusted in one stack then you'll be gladly accepted in other stacks as **"TRUSTED USER"** and you'll get  access for most of common features which really helps to contribute in all other stacks. *I highly encourages ME and our members to take a GLANCE at other stacks and if you think you can help it then even CONTRIBUTE ☺*.

> 4. A moderator role that is unusually relevant in this community (as opposed to others) is taking “political” initiative, i.e., steering the community by means of meta posts and similar. What are your ambitions in this respect? Are there any pressing issues you would like to address and how do you plan to do so?

Indeed mature question for me from @Wrzlprmft♦! I believes that anything can be misused either it is post or product or just a resource like air but the thing matters is how the audience is! i.e. If the audience will be **contaminated group** then for sure they'll cheers for *abuses* but in good **civilized group** it'll totally *restricted*. In our case, I know that *MODERATOR* can misuse the title but I'm sure that by my *WILL OF FIRE* (ambition) towards graphic design will completely help me to avoid doing such things and even if situation goes wrong then even moderators should be judged strictly like others because ***"No ones are superior than rules! Not even super users!"***

> 5. Name an individual action that showcases your suitability as a moderator, for example an individual meta post, review action, or comment (please provide a link to it). Why do you think that this a good example?

First of all, I didn't took very much moderating actions but I've took help of the moderators when I just started using this site to [reduce spam posts](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3583/too-much-spam) also I've accessed **"Review Tasks"** and not but least I've *flagged* plenty of posts which wasn't related to graphic design!

> 6. [Recently][1], there have been tentative ideas to be more open to Critique questions than we have been in the past. What is your stance on this and the way it is being decided? Were/are there things you would do differently? How would you contribute to this process and discussion?

As mentioned in answers of that question: *"Site is like a bar rather than private clubs which are normally cooler!"* If we assume that someone just randomly drew something and want to critique his work in community even though its not for **commercial/professional purposes** (assume random character drawing etc.) then he'll just ask that does character shows a certain expressions and the community might respond too with answers like the eye need to be modified, everything is perfect, you need to modify lips a bit etc. *So some topics like critique are more like opinions rather then questions so there should be no STRICT BOUNDARIES but some guidelines are necessary to keep the topics more strong!*

> 7. How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?

As I said earlier: ***"Rules should be same for everyone!"***. It's the duty of the moderator to look on flagged posts because one or two flag might be a fluke but if the user keeps generating flags after the answer than it only means that either his answer is **poorly explained/tested** because it led to such a big confusions or the answer was the best that it **overcame the question and opened new gates and directions towards the problems**! Depending on the situation, *I might consult other moderators before taking a serious actions which later may cause me/others regrets!*

> 8. How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc a question that you feel shouldn't have been?

All moderators must have a reason before taking such critical actions but still just in case I'm against those action then before doing something I'll talk with the moderator who took action and will try to understand the reason behind it and after that if I still think that it shouldn't have happened then *I'll put my opinion among all moderators with proper reason!*

> 9. A diamond will be attached to everything you say and have said in the past, including questions, answers and comments. Everything you will do will be seen under a different light. How do you feel about that?

### If you think that I deserve "♦" then you've got "♥" from me ^^

> 10. How many graphic designers does it take to change a lightbulb?

Please ask the ***clients!*** I'll put as much as they want just to hear: ***"It's great and I'm impressed"*** if you know what I mean :/ LOL.

Comment: Dont take this the wrong way, you're cute and all, but you talk like an anime character. Which is actually funny.

Comment: @PaulEffect I'm die hard fan of anime :v maybe I'm going toooo deep in anime :P

Comment: I voted for you but I really wish you'd use a little bit less formatting, especially with headers and bold texts: I know you try to put accents but it's quite distracting. Cheers!

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy Thanks for counting me worthy for that! I'll try my best and please keep giving suggesting me :D